# Unable to catch email body with Cypress-Mailosaur

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, multi-factor-authentication, cypress-mailosaur

This the email. It is in HTML and I am trying to retrieve the code
[image: Email]

I am getting this
[image: Error]

I just put an assertion just to check if I am getting the body of the email but the error says it's ''

Comment: is this a coding question?

Comment: What is the output you get when you retrieve the email with mailosaur?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Emails typically have two parts, an html part and a text part. This is so that when you are reading an email on a device that doesn't support html (rare these days) the text version can be shown.

To answer your question: you need to change your code to use email.html.body rather than email.text.body as you don't have a text version of your email.

You should be able to retrieve your authentication code via email.html.codes[0] as well.